# Como pegar os dados de um array e distribuir dentro de um método?

Tags: php

Estou querendo criar um método de cadastrado da seguinte forma:

Na página de produtos:

```
require_once('metodos/metodosClass.php');
$metodos = new metodosClass();
....
// Cadastrar produtos
$tabela = 'produtos';
$camposTB = array('Nome,Descricao,Valor,ValorDesconto');
$valores = array_filter($_POST);
echo $metodos->cadastrarProdutos($tabela,$campoTB,$valores);
```

Porém como eu faria para pegar os valores das variáveis **$camposTB** e **$valores** e distribuir dentro do método **cadastrarProdutos()**?

```
public function cadastrarProdutos($tabela, $camposTB, array $valores)
{
   mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO ".$tabela." ("{INCLUIR OS VALORES DA VARIÁVEL $camposTB}")") VALUES("{INCLUIR OS VALORES DA VARIÁVEL $valores}")");
```

Minha intenção é criar um método genérico, independente da quantidade de campos tenha a query.

Comment: Um dos problema com esse código é a [injeção de SQL](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php) e a dificuldade de tratar os parâmetros. Essa classe fatalmente irá violar *Princípio Aberto-Fechado* pois a primeira chance dessa abordagem ser inadequada ou insuficiente para um conjunto de dados você forçosamente terá que modificar o projeto ou adicionando métodos criando uma classe espaguete ou remendar esse método com gabiarras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sugiro que, nesse caso, você utilize [*prepared statements*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), presentes tanto no [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) como na interface OO do MySQLi, para evitar as famosas *injeções de SQL*, as quais podem indicar a vulnerabilidade do seu sistema, podemos assim dizer.

De qualquer forma, aqui apresento uma solução usando o método que você pede, e outra usando o método "mais seguro".

#### Usando as funções `mysqli_*`

```php
public function cadastrarProdutos(string $tabela, array $campos, array $valores) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tabela";
    $query .= ' (' . implode(', ', $campos) . ') ';
    $query .= 'VALUES (\n';

    //Aqui adiciona aspas para todos os valores e escapa as que já vieram no valor. Ou seja,
    // se o texto veio como 'Olá, 'mundo'!', transformará em
    // 'Olá \'mundo\'!'
    $valores = array_map(function($item) { return "'".addslashes($item)."'"; }, $valores);
    $query .= implode(', ', $valores);
    $query .= '\n);';

    mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    //...
}
```

#### Usando *prepared statements* com `PDO`

Tendo, obviamente, feito todas as configurações do PDO, o método poderia ficar dessa forma:

```php
public function cadastrarProdutos(string $tabela, array $campos, array $valores) {
     $statement = $this->pdoConn->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tabela . ' (' . implode(', ', $campos) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', str_split( str_repeat('?', count($campos) ) ) ) . ');');
     for ($i=0;$i<count($campos);$i++) {
         $statement->bindValue($i+1, array_values($valores)[$i]);
     }
     $statement->execute();
}
```

Aqui utilizo o `for` para poder pegar cada valor e sua respectiva posição, já que, na lógica, a sequência dos elementos na *array* dos valores deve ser a mesma da *array* dos campos (assim como o tamanho de ambas deve ser o mesmo), usando assim o parâmetro `bindValue` para substituir o valor na posição equivalente ao campo dela. Ou seja, o comando SQL no início ficaria assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO produtos (Nome, Descricao, Valor, ValorDesconto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

E depois que tendo sido feitas todas as substituições, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO produtos (Nome, Descricao, Valor, ValorDesconto) VALUES ('<nome>', '<desc>', '<valor>'|<valor>, '<valor_desconto>'|<valor_desconto>);
```

**OBS.:** as notações `'<valor>'|<valor>` e `'<valor_desconto>'|<valor_desconto>` indicam que o valor a ser inserido pode ser um texto ou um valor numérico.

E, em ambas as formas, você poderia criar um "algoritmo" pra saber o tipo do valor e assim passar da forma "correta" para o comando SQL, diferenciando os que são textos e os que são números, seja através da forma manual (a primeira solução), seja pelos *prepared statements*, usando o método `bindValue`, que até possui o parâmetro [`data_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php), que por padrão aceita todos como sendo uma *string*.

#### Usando *prepared statements* com `mysqli` (orientado a objetos)

Adicionalmente, você também pode utilizar os *prepared statements* com a "interface" orientada a objetos do MySQLi, que você pode ver melhor na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) como usar, e fazer de forma parecida à do PDO:

```php
public function cadastrarProdutos(string $tabela, array $campos, array $valores) {
     $statement = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $tabela . ' (' . implode(', ', $campos) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', str_split( str_repeat('?', count($campos) ) ) ) . ');');
     $statement->bind_param("ssss", ...array_values($valores));
     $statement->execute();
     //$statement->close();
}
```

A questão do significado daqueles `"ssss"`, você também pode ver na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), mas, basicamente, estou informando que todos os valores que estão para serem colocados no comando, são *strings*. E após, uso o *spread operator* (operador de "espalhamento", em tradução livre) para passar os valores da *array* como parâmetros, mas, pode haver outras formas (melhores) de se fazer. E aqui vem, mais uma vez, a possibilidade de você mudar os valores para os tipos (de dados) corretos, conforme suas necessidades.

#### Conclusão

Por fim, para utilizar o método `cadastrarProdutos`, qualquer que seja a forma escolhida das apresentadas acima, seria:

```php
require "...";

$tabela = "produtos";
$campos = array('Nome', 'Descricao', 'Valor', 'ValorDesconto');
$valores = array_filter($_POST);
$metodos->cadastrarProdutos($tabela, $campos, $valores);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Com `PDO` é a melhor abordagem para o problema.

Comment: Na verdade, nesse caso, tanto o PDO como (a "interface" orientada a objetos do) MySQLi oferecem métodos para preparar os comandos SQL, isto é, colocar os valores de forma segura, para que não haja a injeção de SQL. Mas, posso citar que o PDO pode ser uma vantagem, já que suporta uma maior variedade de banco de dados, sem mesmo mudar os métodos utilizados. Se eu estiver errado, ou algo não estiver bem argumentado/fundamentado, por favor me corrija.

Comment: Realmente, vi a documentação do MySQLi e não aparenta haver limitações de funcionalidade com relação ao PDO a principal diferença é especificidade do banco de dados.

Comment: Na verdade, se assumir que o `$campos` também é uma entrada controlada pelo usuário (exemplo: site.com/?coluna=valor), ele pode injetar um SQL malicioso da mesma forma, em ambos os casos. Além disos no caso do `bind_param` o primeiro parametro tem que ter o mesmo número (e tipo) do valor $valores.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorando problemas de segurança, você poderia usar o `implode` normalmente.

```
$tabela = 'produtos';
$camposTB = ['Nome','Descricao','Valor','ValorDesconto']; // Cada coluna é um item
$valores = array_filter($_POST);

echo $metodos->cadastrarProdutos($tabela,$campoTB,$valores);
```

Então:

```
public function cadastrarProdutos(string $tabela, array $campos, array $valores)
{
   $campos = '`' . implode($campos, '`,`') . '`';
   $valores = '"' . implode($valores, '","') . '"';
   mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO ".$tabela." (".$campos.") VALUES (".$valores.")");
}
```